# why do most sensors have an electrical output, regardless of the physical nature of the variable being measured

Tags: sensor, control-system

I have been trying to figure out a explanation to this question, can someone explain this ?

Comment: Because it is intended to go to some electrical input.

Comment: The entire point of a transducer is to convert a physical parameter to an electrical one; or the opposite of that. Sensors are transducers. Speakers are transducers. Microphones are transducers. etc.

Comment: Add the fact that the electrical signal can be displayed remotely...

Comment: Because we use electrical systems to connect them to, so we want an output signal electrical systems understand (and those are: electrical signals).

Comment: Imagine sensors without output data. _"Hey guys! Guess what I just saw/felt/heard?"_ Who cares? It's not like we do anything with your observations....

Comment: It is wider than just sensors. Copper wire is very thin and flexible and can be joined by contact. That is at the heart of its advantage. Imagine any circuit board implemented with tube.

Comment: I suppose one could design a sensor that has the sensor output of liquid and liters/min but it might be hard to send the output into a micro controller (and have it still function).

Comment: somewhat related: [Difference between sensors and transducers](https://makersconfidential.blogspot.com/2015/04/difference-between-sensors-and-transducers.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do most sensors have an electrical output, regardless of the physical nature of the variable being measured?

Electrical control systems have the following advantages over alternatives such as mechanical, pneumatic, hydraulic, etc.

- **Speed**. Electrical control systems are fast.
- **Size**. The control systems can be miniaturised.
- **Power**. Electricity is readily available. No compressors or pumps are required.
- **Reliability**. Electro-mechanical (relay) systems can have high reliability despite the moving parts. Solid-state (transistor, triac, etc.) can have far higher reliability as there are no moving parts.
- **Distance**. Electrical signals can be transmitted long distances without significant loss.
- **Cost**. Mechanical control systems require precision components which can be more expensive to manufacture and calibrate.
- **Versatility**. Electrical systems are very versatile. Transducers are available to convert light, sound, pressure, force, strain, radioactivity, viscosity, temperature, velocity, etc., into electrical signals.

The last one is probably the most important. While, for example, pneumatic logic and control systems exist and have their benefits (explosive atmospheres, for example) it is difficult to imagine how a light to air pressure transducer is going to beat a light-dependent resistor. In other applications such as temperature control mechanical solutions - car coolant thermostat, for example - are more than adequate.

Answer (score 8):

That's easy- spirit of the time. Current technology is all about electronics. A hundred years ago it was different, Litmus for example hasn't electrical output :)

Comment: Or even 60 years ago it was pneumatic. The 4ma->20mA current loop signaling comes directly from pneumatic control systems of the early 20th century.

Comment: The canary was a sensor - used down a coal mine and when it fell of its perch it was time to evacuate +1 for spirit of the time.

Comment: Yeah, disposable biotech high end gas sensor!

Comment: Optical fibres are sometimes used when electricity is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sensors could press on or retract a pushrod.

With air-bearings, the wear factor would be excellent (long duration sensing).

But imaging the task of instrumenting a nuclear-test-site, with lots of crucial measurements having impulse-responses of nanoseconds or microseconds. The pushrod inertial serves as a low-pass-filter; the exploration of uranium at Los Alamos might still be underway, and USA might now be speaking German.

Comment: A push rod is hardier against radiation than [today's typical] electronics, though.

Comment: I occasionally wonder how humanity will develop those generational spacecraft, ready for 100,000 year voyages between the stars. Certainly the Air Conditioning systems will run through fan bearings every 100 years, thus 1,000 sets of A/C bearings must be placed in ship-stores, or bearing-manufacturing is one of the human skill sets places onboard.